# Relationship between LU Factors and Cholesky Factors

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Can someone please help me explain whether there exists a relationship between the LU Factor and the Cholesky Factor?

Some sources said that it holds L^T = U. However I tried to see it in an actual matrix and failed to prove it.

Lets consider this matrix:
A   =
⌈2  -1   0⌉
|-1  2  -1｜
⌊0  -1   2⌋

Cholesky:
L=
⌈1.414    0      0  ⌉
|-0.707 1.225    0  ｜
⌊   0   -0.816  1.155⌋

L^T=
⌈1.414  -0.707    0   ⌉
|   0   1.225   -0.816｜
⌊   0     0      1.155⌋

LU:
L=
⌈  1    0   0⌉
|-0.5   1   0｜
⌊  0  -0.67 1⌋

U=
⌈  2   -1     0⌉
|  0   1.5   -1｜
⌊  0    0  1.33⌋

I realised that for LU factorization, the L and U matrix will differ based on my pivoting. Does the pivoting will affect the relationship between LU factors and Cholesky factors?